# Makefile adding libraries from others directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, libraries

I want to create a Makefile for a big C project, with files divided into directories. What I wrote is

```
CC              =  gcc
AR              =  ar
ARFLAGS         =  rvs
CFLAGS          += -std=c99 -Wall -g

INCDIR          = ./include
LIBDIR          = ./lib
SRCDIR          = ./src
BINDIR          = ./bin
OBJDIR          = ./obj
TESTDIR         = ./testfile

INCLUDES        = -I.
LDFLAGS         = -L/lib
LIBFUNCTIONS    = /-lfunctions
LIBTH           = -lpthread
LIBUTILITY      = /-lutility
OPTFLAGS        = -O3 -DNDEBUG

TARGETS         =   $(BINDIR)/test_functions        \

.PHONY: all clean cleanall test1 test2
.SUFFIXES: .c .h

$(BINDIR)/%: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(OPTFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(OPTFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

all     : $(TARGETS)        

$(BINDIR)/test_functions: $(OBJDIR)/test_functions.o $(LIBDIR)/libutility.a $(LIBDIR)/libfunctions.a
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(FLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBUTILITY) $(LIBFUNCTIONS)

$(OBJDIR)/test_functions.o: $(SRCDIR)/test_functions.c $(INCDIR)/utility.h $(LIBDIR)/libutility.a $(INCDIR)/functions.h $(LIBDIR)/libfunctions.a
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<           

$(LIBDIR)/libutility.a: $(OBJDIR)/utility.o $(INCDIR)/utility.h
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<  

$(LIBDIR)/libfunctions.a: $(OBJDIR)/functions.o $(INCDIR)/functions.h $(INCDIR)/utility.h
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<  


clean       : 
    rm -f $(TARGETS)

cleanall    : clean
    \rm -f *.o *~
```

the problem is that when I try to compile the project using the makefile, the result is

```
gcc  -std=c99 -Wall -g -I.  -L/lib -o bin/test_functions obj/test_functions.o -lutility -lfunctions
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lutility
/usr/bin/ld: impossibile trovare -lfunctions
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:54: bin/test_functions] Error 1
```

it seems that the compiler cannot find the libraries. what can I do to make it work properly?

Comment: You do not need to use `-lutility` and `-lfunctions` because they are static libraries.  Also, `-L/lib` doesn't do anything either because that is a standard library path.  If you were linking against shared libraries in `./lib` , you would want the `-l` options and `-L./lib`.

Comment: More info [here](https://medium.com/@StueyGK/static-libraries-vs-dynamic-libraries-af78f0b5f1e4)

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
LIBDIR          = ./lib
```

then in your link line you have this:

```
LDFLAGS         = -L/lib
```

Notice the difference?

Why don't you just say:

```
LDFLAGS = -L$(LIBDIR)
```

to avoid repeating yourself (and getting it wrong)?